# Splitting columns in excel

Tags: excel, split

I have a data set about number of shoes owned that I'm attempting to split. Here are several lines of it, but there are 700 in total:

```
 Age     Shoes     Gender
 17      9         Female
 37      5         Male
 27      13        Female
 59      8         Male
 .....
```

I want to split the Gender column into two columns, but I am having a challenging time with it because then the Age and Shoes columns are effected. Is there any way to create something below:

```
 Age     Shoes     Gender     Age     Shoes     Gender
 17      9         Female     37      5         Male
 27      13        Female     59      8         Male
 .....
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to calculate the average number of shoes owned by men and women? I would also like to calculate other basic statistics like the standard deviation of each. Is this possible in the current format my data is in?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Lizzie

Comment: Have you looked into using Pivot Tables?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have never heard of a Pivot Table, is that a route I should go?

Comment: Take a look at pivot tables. Once you create one, you will be blown away with how powerful they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Average:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$5,$C$2:$C$5,"Female")
```

For Standard Deviation:

```
=STDEV.S(IF($C$2:$C$5="Female",$B$2:$B$5))
```

This is an array formula.  It needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving ecit mode instead of Enter.

You can change the STDEV.S to MEDIAN and other Statistical formulas to get what you need.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! This is just what I needed!